# MYSQL DATE range Query with date format

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL table with field name "date" in the formate "dd/mm";

I need to query results from 20/06 to 22/06 (3 days data),  this is how I am trying to do it.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `wtt` WHERE date BETWEEN '20/06' AND '22/06';
```

But MYSQL is also selecting the dates 22/04, 22/05 and other entries.

Is there MYSQL query which will fetch me the right answer without the need to change the format in which I have already stored the information in the MYSQL table?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert the dates to MySQL date types and then compare them.

You can convert the dates like this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('20/06', '/', EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURDATE())),'%d/%m/%Y');
```

or simply

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20/06','%d/%m');
```

for year 0000 if it doesn't matter.

Storing dates as strings has brought this problem on you. You should always use DATE type for storing dates.

Comment: I understand now, the above query results "0000-06-20".
How would the query be to select the results to for a range of dates?
I tried many combination none of them worked :(
I'm new to this, thank you for your patience.

Comment: I got it,
SELECT * FROM `wtt` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m') BETWEEN '0000-06-20' AND '0000-06-22';

Thank you a ton!